# Making grid Resizable when browser window is resized

Tags: extjs

I used `monitorResize:true` when rendering out a grid to a window (`Ext.Window`). But that doesn't do the trick.

```
CListingEditorGrid =  new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
      id: 'CListingEditorGrid',
      renderTo:'grid_div',
      viewConfig:{
        forceFit:true // CHANGED THIS
    },
      store: CDataStore,
      cm: CColumnModel,
      sm:selmodel,
      enableColLock:false,
      clicksToEdit:1,
      selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect:false}),
      plugins:[filters],
      bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar(
    {
    store:CDataStore,
    pageSize:10,
    plugins: [filters]
    }),
      tbar: [{
         text: 'Add Contact',
         tooltip: 'Add Contact',
         handler: displayFormWindow
      },
      {
              text:'Delete Contact',
              tooltip:'Delete Contact',
              handler:deleteContacts
      }
      ]
    });
CListingWindow = new Ext.Window({
      id: 'CListingWindow',
      title: 'Contacts List',
      closable:true,
      width:1000,
      height:500,
      layout: 'fit',
      items: [CListingEditorGrid],
      renderTo:'grid_div',
      resizable:false

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few mistakes:

1. the `renderTo` should not be used by two components and point to same div. This is not a correct way.
2. You can render the whole thing without even using the elements. Try the following code:

```
var CListingEditorGrid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    //normally, we don't assign ids if there is no obvious reason to use this.
    //id: 'CListingEditorGrid',

    //We don't need this as this grid will be rendered into the window
    //renderTo: 'grid_div',
    viewConfig: {
        //forceFit is used by the GridView, so to have the GridView
        //fits into the grid, not grid fits into the window
        forceFit: true
    },
    store: CDataStore,
    cm: CColumnModel,

    //You don't need to have this
    //sm: selmodel,
    enableColLock: false,
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    //The default sm is already multi-selectable so you could probably
    //remove this selModel.
    /*
    selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({

        singleSelect: false
    }),
    */
    plugins: [filters],
    bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
        store: CDataStore,
        pageSize: 10,
        plugins: [filters]
    }),
    tbar: [{
        text: 'Add Contact',
        tooltip: 'Add Contact',
        handler: displayFormWindow
    }, {
        text: 'Delete Contact',
        tooltip: 'Delete Contact',
        handler: deleteContacts
    }]
});

var CListingWindow = new Ext.Window({
    //id: 'CListingWindow',
    title: 'Contacts List',
    //closable: true,
    width: 1000,
    height: 500,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [CListingEditorGrid],
    //renderTo: 'grid_div',
    resizable: false
});

//Show this window
CListingWindow.show();
```

Update us if it work. I haven't test it yet. But the grid should fit the window nicely with the parameter `layout:'fit'`.

Comment: It is working the problem was as you said in renderTo - Thanks

Comment: No problem :) You can learn more from the provided examples, or check out their source codes, lots of goodies!

Answer (score 2):

assuming you are using ext 3...

try this one:

```
var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: [{name: 'Id'},{name: 'Name'},{name: 'Email'}],
    data: [
        ['1','Egy','egy.mohammad.r@callysta-engineering.com'],
        ['2','Ebo','mohammad.erdin@gmail.com']
    ]
});
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    viewConfig :{
        forceFit : true // thisfor force fit the grid (no horizontal scroll)
    },
    columns: [
        {header: 'Id',dataIndex: 'Id'},
        {header: 'Name',dataIndex: 'Name'},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'Email'}
    ]
});
var win = new Ext.Window({
    layout:'fit',
    title : "resizeable",
    width:500,
    height:300,
    closeAction:'hide',
    items: [grid]
});
win.show(this);
```

there are 2 mistake here :

1. `monitorResize` is not one of kind configs in `Ext.Window` or `Ext.grid.GridPanel`
2. when you use `Ext.Window` and want to fit the content inside.. use `layout: "fit"` config.

Comment: I made the changes but it is not working . I am rendering it to a <div> element and the changes are uses forceFit:true in GridEditorPanel and i had already used layout:'fit'

Comment: try show me your current code by update your question.. maybe i could help you.. (i think i missunderstand)

Comment: i see the problem... you define a `CListingEditorGrid` and render it to a `grid_div`... and you define a window, containing `CListingEditorGrid` and render it to `grid_div` also... i think you dont need a window if you want render `editorGridPanel` to div... but if so, i'll search the answer for you.. i'll edit my answer when i got it...